# Cannot inject a local EJB. Dependency Injection failed

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.1

I'm using glassfish 3.1 and JEE6 with EJB3.1.  I'm simply trying to inject one Stateless LocalBean with the no-interface view into another EJB so that I can access one of its methods. But I immediately get a deployment error on the injection site.

If I inject its interface @EJB Interface interface;

> Cannot resolve reference Local ejb-ref name=com.sallie.logic.RSSbean/tclient,Local 3.x interface =com.eb
>   .thriftEJBinterfaces.thriftEJBinterf**ace,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=,r**efType=Session

If I inject it through no-interface view as in @EJB myBean bean;

- javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/com
- javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref
- javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: c
- javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/c

No matter how I do the injection it doesn't work. I have other EJBs doing the exact same thing in this project that work fine. My database access object uses injection and it's still running. For some reason this EJB will not inject.

**Edit:** class declaration with annotation: (basically this class creates a socket connection to an external server not on my web app but that is available at that address using a IDL called thrift. This was tested and works on it's on as a java SE program (NOTE:THE SERVER LOG ERRORS DO NOT INDICATE THAT THIS IS A PROBLEM. THE LOG FILES THROW REFERENCE AND NAMING EXCEPTIONS AS IF THEY CANNOT FIND THE EJB).

```
package com.eb.thrift;

import com.eb.thrift.sendEventMessage2;
import com.eb.thriftEJBinterfaces.thriftEJBinterface;

import org.apache.thrift.TException;
import org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol;
import org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket;
import org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException;

import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;
import javax.ejb.Remote;
import javax.ejb.Local;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class ThriftClient{

    public ThriftClient() { }

    public String sendToServer(String say) {
        System.out.println("Entering ThriftClient's main method starting server connection...");

        String msg = null;
        //**Make Socket**
        TSocket socket = new TSocket("982.222.33.44", 30888);

        //**Make Buffer**
        //TSocket bufferedSocket = (socket); skipping this step because the jvm already handles
        //the buffering on this end. 

        //**put in protocol**
        TBinaryProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(socket);
        //**create client to use protocol encoder**
        sendEventMessage2.Client client = new sendEventMessage2.Client(protocol);
        //**connect**
        try {
            socket.open();
        } catch (TTransportException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            client.ping();
        } catch (TException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            msg = client.sayMsg(say);
            return msg;
        } catch (TException e) {
            msg = "response from server failed";
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        socket.close();
        return msg;
    }
}
```

I've tried this with and without the interface because I'm using 3.1 I can use no-interface view and it didn't solve the problem.

I'm wondering if I could use some annotation parameters to explicitly set the mapping and name so that the reference can be found better.

Comment: Can you include the class declaration (with annotations) for the bean you are trying to inject?

Comment: @Perception  added the class declaration I dont know that it will help. I've been using this form for 3 or 4 other EJBs and it works fine. For some reason it doesn't like THIS EJB and I think it's because of what I'm trying to do inside of the EJB and the error is just misleading. Because when I comment out the body of my EJB Glassfish allows me to inject it without problem and it deploys.

Comment: "Because when I comment out the body of my EJB Glassfish allows me to inject it without problem and it deploys." If that's the case then you should post the whole body.

Comment: Your annotations look fine. The next likelihood being that your container cannot instantiate the bean to be injected. Are you using the Apache thrift classes successfully in other beans?

Comment: I've never successfully used this as a bean but it did work fine as a regular java SE application. It's a Thrift Client so it's connecting to a server. I realize there might be problems with this but why would the errors be in regards to locating the EJB shouldn't the errors have come from runtime exceptions dealing with whatever specific method or class was the issue? not just "EJB naming exception" as a general fail.

Comment: @gurung I've updated the class to contain the full body

Comment: Small hint: you probably don't need both a no-interface view and a local view. If you want to inject without an interface, remove **both** the LocalBean and the interface. If you want to inject via an interface, remove LocalBean. This annotation is only needed when you sometimes want to inject with and sometimes without interface. This is a bit weird, so usage of LocalBean should be rare and not something you just add "because everyone on SO does it"

Comment: Thank you @MikeBraun, I was mixing different styles as I was attempting to solve the problem some one told me to try an interface instead of no-interface so I think I got a half and half version going on. But actually to your point I think it's more rare to NOT use no-interface with JEE6 AND EJB 3.1 why create a local interface when you could just use the @ LocalBean annotation?

Comment: @Randum I'm afraid you still don't get it. You **do not** need the @ LocalBean annotation in order to get a no-interface view. Create a bean with NO interface and NO @ LocalBean annotation. ONLY use @ Stateless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you've proved that, despite what the logs say, the Thrift code *is* the problem. If you remove it, injection works; if you leave it in, injection fails. That points very strongly at the Thrift code.

I suspect that this is a classloading problem. The app server can't find the Thrift libraries, or finds the wrong version, and as a result, the class doesn't load, or can't be instantiated. That failure means the EJB can't be instantiated, which means the lookup fails.

You would expect the underlying exception causing the failure to be logged, but this might be a bug or oversight in the app server. That kind of thing does happen depressingly often.

I'd try writing a really simple test version of the EJB that does:

```
try {
    System.err.println(Class.forName("org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket"));
}
catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e);
}
```

And see what you get when the method is invoked.

Comment: this was the output:

SEVERE: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket
 at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClassData(ASURLClassLoader.java:808)
 at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClass(ASURLClassLoader.java:696)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)

Comment: Accepting as answer.  You saw right through those misleading server logs. Thanks man. Now to find out why glassfish can't see these library files...for another topic!

Comment: Really, @Perception's second comment had the solution. I just spelled it out in a little more detail.